# jsp: Place the footer at the bottom of the page included in another jsp and make content scrollable

Tags: css, jsp

I have a jsp included in another jsp. The header and footer are placed in the original jsp (and not the one which is included). I want to either fix my footer at the bottom of the page and make the content scrollable in case of an overflow or make the footer scroll with the page as well. I have tried all the "fix footer" and "scroll content" solutions I can find on SO. None of them seem to work. 
Here's my code:

```
<body class="landingPage">
<div class="header">
</div>
<div class="mainClass">
    <div class= "banner">
        <p>Welcome </p>
    </div>
    <div align="center" class="Content"> 
        <%@ include file="jsp/page1.jsp" %>

    </div>
    </div>
    <div id="footer">&copy;
        <%=Calendar.getInstance().get(Calendar.YEAR) %>
    All rights reserved.
    </div>
</body>
```

And the CSS:

```
html, body {
    height: 100%;
    overflow: hidden;
}

body {
    margin: 0;
}

.Content {
    width: 100%;
    display: inline-block;
    overflow-y: auto;
    height: 90%;
}

.mainClass {
    margin: 10px 20px 0px 0px;
    border-top: 10px;
    border-left: 30px;
    padding: 5px 0px 15px 15px;
}

.footer {
    background-color: #edf2fc;
    color: #0544aa;
    position: static;
    right: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    left: 0;
    padding: 1rem;
    text-align: center;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Please try this in your css to fix the position of the footer to the bottom of the page.

```
#footer {
    background-color: #edf2fc;
    color: #0544aa;
    position: fixed;
    right: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    left: 0;
    padding: 1rem;
    text-align: center;
}
```

Comment: This breaks when the content of my body starts to overflow.

Comment: Have you tried with after i have edited the code, before one semicolon was missing from the css.

Comment: This was one of the first solutions that you find on SO. Yes, I had already tried it before posting my question.

Comment: Hi Abhineet..it  is little difficult to assume you code and do a fix..if possible can you please do a jsfiddle, that bit will be easier to debug the issue.